# Horizontal Scrolling on iOS without Vertical Bounce or Extra-Fast Inertia

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile-safari, horizontal-scrolling

I’m working on a horizontally scrolling website and am running into two codependent iOS scroll issues. The fist issue is that my horizontal scroll area bounces vertically (or rubber bands) in way that’s very annoying. The second is that the css inertial scroll property **-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch** scrolls twice as fast as normal inertial scrolling on iOS and this extra speed causes rendering issues. I can solve either issue independently but each workaround creates the other issue.

Is there any way to get inertial scrolling in the horizontal direction while also preventing vertical dragging?

**First here’s a simplified form of my markup:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wide-content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS Option 1: Wide Body, Unwanted Vertical Drag**

```
html, body {
    width: 10000px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

#wide-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here I set my body and html element to be as wide as my content. The scrolling works naturally. But if a user drags the content up or down, the entire scroll area moves. The vertical motion can fire simultaneously to any horizontal scrolling which feels very distracting. The image linked below shows how the page appears when someone pulls from the upper-left corner.

[image: Horizotnal Scroll with Unwanted Vertical Drag]

**CSS Option 2: Narrow Body with overflow: scroll, Intertial Scrolling is too fast**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#wide-content {
    width: 100000px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

This style option uses a narrow body container that’s glued to the viewport edges. The body is set to overflow: scroll and the scroll content now has a large width value. I also add the special webkit property to give the scrolling inertia. There still is some vertical bounce, but the content can only move in one direction at a time so the scrolling experience is much better. The problem is that -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch produces inertial scrolling that is about twice as fast as the iOS default scroll option.

Why not just accept the faster scrolling? The scroll content contains large images. If a user scrolls too quickly the edges of the images flicker distractingly due to iOS rendering glitches. The extra inertia substantially increases the chance that of the user seeing the rendering bugs. If there's any way to prevent the edges from flickering as they scroll horizontally into view, I would be happy to use this CSS option.